# How to insert a row into one table in sql that is exact same as another table but only one column different?

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have a table and I want to insert a new row that is exactly the same as one row EXCEPT with one column value different.

```
col1 col2 col3
joe  ben  sam
```

My desired output for the new row being added would be

```
col1 col2 col3
bob  ben  sam
joe  ben  sam
```

As you can see the original column is still there but we added a new row with the first value being changed from joe to bob.

Any ideas on the most elegant way to do this maybe without hard coding?  I was thinking maybe an insert based on a select * where condition but not sure. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT INTO (SELECT & VALUES) TOGETHER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244563/insert-into-select-values-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
insert into t (col1, col2, col3) select 'joe', col2, col3 from t
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for thank you very much!  I forget you can select the value like that.  Perfect!

Comment: Tou don't mention the specific database, so the syntax may vary a bit. See the manual of the specific engine.